# I have two accounts with the same name.

Tags: support

Last year I joined math SE and several later I returned to math SE and accidentally and without any purpose I opened another account with the same name. I am using the later account now and I want to delete my previous account. What can I do?

My previous account is (user:32176)

My current account is (user:56706)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: To have your accounts _merged_, follow the directions [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).  To _delete_ an account follow the directions [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account).

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Thanks Arthur, but I have no access to my previous account anymore and since I use the same computer and the same email address for my current account I cannot add the phrase "merge delete" to the about me section of my previous account.

Comment: What happens if you enter that email address at [Account Recovery](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery)?

Comment: I didn't enter my email. because I have used the same email for both accounts and probably I receive login information about my current account which is unnecessary. I have sent a message to Help Center and I hope they can fix it.